# Discuss the monotonicity of $\sqrt[n]{n!}$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

It seems that $\sqrt[n]{n!}$ is increasing because it turns to $+\infty$ as $n\to+\infty$. How to prove it?

Comment: Try proving it by induction. Or as you have given the tag calculus, differentiate it to show that it is always positive for positive integers.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan: "differentiate"? Are you referring to the gamma function?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan In fact I don't know how to differentiate a function containing factorial.

Comment: Clearly we have $n!<(n+1)^n$. Now mutiply by $(n!)^n$ and take the $n(n+1)$-root

Comment: If you want to go the differentiation route, you can replace $n!$ by $\Gamma(n+1)$. However, if you don’t find the result is increasing, that doesn’t mean your original sequence is not increasing. It’s only a sufficient condition. That is $f(x)$ increasing implies $f(n)$ increasing, but $f(x)$ non increasing doesn’t necessarily mean $f(n)$ is non increasing.

Comment: Is your goal to prove increasing monotonicity, or to prove that it diverges to $+\infty$? Because neither of those implies the other.

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to show that $\frac{1}{n}\log(n!)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log(k)$ is increasing.
Since $\log(x)$ is concave on $\mathbb{R}^+$, this is a simple consequence of [Karamata's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata%27s_inequality):

$$ \tfrac{1}{n}\cdot\log(1)+\tfrac{1}{n}\cdot\log(2)+\ldots+\tfrac{1}{n}\cdot\log(n)+0\cdot \log(n+1)\\ \leq \tfrac{1}{n+1}\cdot\log(1)+\tfrac{1}{n+1}\cdot\log(2)+\ldots+\tfrac{1}{n+1}\log(n+1).$$

---

As an alternative approach, $n!^{n+1}\leq (n+1)!^n$ is equivalent to $n!\leq (n+1)^n$ which is trivial.

Comment: If you interpret $\log(k)$ as the score you got on the $k$th test, then it makes sense that your *average* score increases as you take more tests.

Comment: @BarryCipra: that is a very nice interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{n!^{n+1}}{(n+1)!^n}
&=\frac{n!}{(n+1)^n}\\
&=\frac1{n+1}\cdot\frac2{n+1}\cdot\frac3{n+1}\cdots\frac{n}{n+1}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Another Hint:** Notice that $n!^{\frac1n}$ is the geometric mean of first $n$ natural numbers. $(n+1)!^{\frac1{n+1}}$ is the geometric mean of the same set of natural numbers and one larger natural number.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n = \sqrt[n]{n!}$

Let's show that $a_{n+1}>a_n$.

Need to show: $\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!} > \sqrt[n]{n!}$

Take $n+1$ power on both sides.

$$(n+1)! > (n!)^{\frac{n+1}{n}}=(n!)^{1+1/n}$$

Divide both sides by $n!$

Then$$n+1 > (n!)^{1/n}$$
$$(n+1)^n > n!$$
Since
$$(n+1)(n+1)\cdots(n+1) > n\cdot (n-1)\cdots 1$$
(Each side has $n $ elements)

(Write backwards to complete the proof)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that for some $n$ we have $$(n+1)!^{\dfrac {1}{n+1}}\leq n!^{\dfrac {1}{n}}$$

Take both sides to the power of $n(n+1)$ to obtain $$(n+1)!^n\leq n!^{n+1}$$

From that we arrive at $$n!^n(n+1)^n\leq n!^nn!$$

And now we obtain $$n^n<(n+1)^n\leq n!$$ which is clearly false so we arrived at a contradiction, so your sequence is strictly increasing.